# MVC4 - URL path issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am very new to MVC 4. Here  I am facing a issue related to URL reference of assets.

I have used bundle configuration to render my css and scripts.

```cs
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/scripts/location")
```

One of my script is using URL of  a CSS and that CSS uses some images.

**1.Image issues:**

Actual reference :
http://localhost:58752/Scripts/lib/sample/img/east-mini.png

> 404 error with following link
>   http://localhost:58752/Location/img/east-mini.png

**2. CSS reference issue**

Actual reference :http://localhost:58752/Scripts/lib/sample/theme/default/style.css

> 404 error with following link http://localhost:58752/Location/theme/default/style.css

Please help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: Provide how you reference these images in a CSS class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Images and other resources inside a CSS file should always be referenced as relative to the location of this CSS file itself.

So for example if you have `Location/theme/default/style.css` and wanted to reference `Location/theme/images/foo.png` you should use `../images/foo.png` inside your CSS.